# Open a specific section within a form

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

I have 3 sections within a form. Is it possible to open a specific section using Lotus Script?

If the answer is no, then are there any tricks to do that?

Answer (score 1):

No simple way, exists: @formula and LotusScript don't give finer grain than collapse expand **all** sections.

The only way is to send keys (controlling the keyboard by using DLL as explain by Richard in the bellow remark). You make a goto field to the field (not in the section) before the section and then send the number of "below key" needed to navigate to the section, then send "+" (which expand the section).

Comment: It's a bit cryptic, but I think this is what @Emmanuel meant:

"There is no simple way. Formula and lotusscript dont support anything finer grain than collapsing or expanding all sections.

The only way would be with the SendKeys function. You would do a uidoc.gotoField to a field that is just before the section, and then send the number of down-arrow key needed to navigate to the section itself, and then send the + key.

Comment: You should note that LotusScript's SendKeys function is not actually supported in the Notes client. (It was intended for other Lotus products that also used LotusScript.) But here's an IBM technote that shows how to use keybd_event from user32.dll to send keystrokes: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21089151

Comment: @RichardSchwartz, you "uncrypt" (or unzip?) perfctly what I meant! I plained to explain this my selft upon author OK that this was a possible solution for him, also I was on my phone when writting this. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can get creative with the hide when's. Can you be a little more specific about what you're wanting?